# How do TensorFlow queue runners work?

Tags: multithreading, tensorflow, queue

I am trying to understand how Queue Runners work. I know that queue runners are used to fill a queue more efficiently, running several enqueuing threads in parallel. But how does the resulting queue look like? What exactly is happening?

Let me make my question more specific:
I have a number of files whose content I want to put in one big queue.

file 1: A, B, C

file 2: D, E, F

file 3: G, H, I

I follow the [TensorFlow input pipeline](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data). I first create a list of filenames, then a queue of filenames using `tf.string_input_producer()`, a reader operation and a decoder. In the end I want to put my serialized examples into an example queue that can be shared with the graph. For this I use a QueueRunner:

```
qr = tf.train.QueueRunner(queue, [enqueue_op] * numberOfThreads)
```

and I add it to the QUEUE_RUNNERS collection:

```
tf.train.add_queue_runner(qr)
```

My enqueue_op enqueues one example at a time. So, when I use e.g. numberOfThreads = 2, how does the resulting queue look like? In which order are the files read into the queue? For example, does the queue look something like

`q = [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I]` (so despite the parallel processing the content of the files is not mixed in the queue)

Or does the queue look rather look like

`q = [A, D, B, E, C, F, G, H, I]` ?

```
def get_batch(file_list, batch_size, input_size,
                     num_enqueuing_threads):

    file_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(file_list) 


    reader = tf.TFRecordReader() 

    _, serialized_example = reader.read(file_queue) 

    sequence_features = {
      'inputs': tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature(shape=[input_size],
                                       dtype=tf.float32),
      'labels': tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature(shape=[],
                                       dtype=tf.int64)}


    _, sequence = tf.parse_single_sequence_example(
      serialized_example, sequence_features=sequence_features)

    length = tf.shape(sequence['inputs'])[0]


    queue = tf.PaddingFIFOQueue(
      capacity=1000,
      dtypes=[tf.float32, tf.int64, tf.int32],
      shapes=[(None, input_size), (None,), ()])

    enqueue_ops = [queue.enqueue([sequence['inputs'],
                            sequence['labels'],
                            length])] * num_enqueuing_threads


    tf.train.add_queue_runner(tf.train.QueueRunner(queue, enqueue_ops))

    return queue.dequeue_many(batch_size)
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually find the [animated figure](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data#aside_what_is_happening_here) of the same page you mention to be rather illustrative.

There is a first queue, the Filename Queue, that feeds file reading threads. Within each of these threads, files are read sequentially -- or rather, according to the order followed by your reader. Each of these threads feed *another* queue, the Example Queue, the output of which is consumed by your training.

In your question, you are interested in the resulting order of the examples in the Example Queue.

The answer depends on how the reader works. The best practice and the most efficient way (illustrated in the animated figure above) is to send a sample to the Example Queue as soon as it is ready. This streaming functionality is usually provided by the [various `Reader` variants proposed by tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/io_ops#readers) to promote and ease this best practice. However it is certainly possible to write a reader that would `enqueue_many` all samples at once at the end.

In all cases, since readers are in separate, non-synchronized threads, you do not have any guarantee in the order of their respective output. For example in the standard, streaming cases, the examples may be interleaved regularly, or not -- virtually anything can happen.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I have several questions left:

1. When looking at the figure it seems as if the filename queue is filled over and over again with the same files. Is that the case? Before, I thought that, once the filename-queue is created, all files will be read until the queue is empty. Since otherwise this process can run forever, right? The example queue will never be empty.

Comment: 2. Let's say I have one reader, namely a tf.TFRecordReader and one dequeue op (tf.parse_single_sequeuence_example) and multiple enqueuing threads using a Queue runner. Could you explain again how these threads would run in parallel and what is happening? Would the effect be similar to having several TFRecord readers?

Comment: 1) this is a functionality of `string_input_producer` (typically used for file inputs) that, when creating the queue, also add an enqueue op that constantly re-feed the queue.

Comment: regarding 2) I have a TFRecordReader and a QueueRunner that runs several enqueuing threads in parallel. That's the usual architecture that I found. I added some code above in the original question!

Comment: 2. Yes, the end result would be the same, ie that you cannot have any guarentee on the order in which data is enqueued.

Comment: regarding 2) could you explain in a bit more detail how the enqueuing threads would run in parallel and what is happening? I still have trouble understanding what's going on when using a single reader but several enqueuing ops